# What am I supposed to do after failing to brew a drink?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

...aside from reconstructing the Still that is. Otherwise, the brew drink option is permanently red, and this window opens upon selecting the option:
[window when seelcting brew drink http://s23.postimg.org/icj2pb515/lol.png](http://s23.postimg.org/icj2pb515/lol.png)

Note: I'm using the [Mayday Tilesest](http://goblinart.pl/vg-eng/df.php) that he provides straight out of the box. As such the DF version is "v40_05, updated 28 VII 2014".

Comment: It might be good to give more information. For example, what does the window that opens when you try to select brew drink look like.

Comment: Actually I do that exact thing. Can you not see the image? o.O

Comment: I indeed see no image. Just the link to the mod source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there isn't really enough information here to figure out what exactly the problem is. Many things can cause issues with workshops.

Assuming that this isn't some issue introduced by whatever the edits to the raws that the "DFG" version introduced, there are several things that can cause a job listing to be red and unavailable.

All of these things boil down to one fact, the workshop believes that it does not have the resources necessary to perform the task. This could be the case for several reasons.

- You really are all out of brewable plants. This is the least likely if you have gotten any sort of farm going, but it can happen in the early days if you brought plump helmet spawn but no plump helmets. To fix this you need to [grow](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Farm), [gather](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Plant_gathering), or [trade](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Trade) for some plants.
- You might be out of [barrels.](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Barrel) Barrels are necessary for the brew plants task, and it fills them up. If this is the case then you should make more barrels. You can make them from wood, glass, metal, or stone at various workshops. You can also make them from pottery, but most of those need extra treatment before they are able to hold liquids.
- The workshop is set to take only from certain [stockpiles](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Stockpile#Give_to_a_stockpile.2Fworkshop). If there is not an incoming stockpile link for **every** resource it needs, including barrels, then it won't be able to do the job. If this is the problem then the fast solution is to remove the restriction on the workshop. Use the 'a' key from the workshop commands screen. (when the cursor is over the workshop in set building task/pref mode activated by 'q' from the base mode.)
- You might have set all of your available plant types to not be brewable in the [kitchen status screen](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Status#Kitchen_Status_Screen). You can see if this is the problem by going to that screen ('z', right-arrow, enter), and seeing if there are all red elements in the brew column on the far right. If this is the case you can set some back to being allowed to be brewed with the arrow keys and the 'b' key.
- Your plants might be forbidden. You can see this from the [stocks status](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Status#Stocks_Status_Screen) screen. Unforbidding the plants will let you brew them if this is the case.
- Your plants might be physically inaccessible. To determine this you would have to examine the structure of your fort. To make them accessible again you could dig, or open any locked doors so that the workshop can reach them.

The other possibility is that the edits made to the raws (which its page say exist) of the DFG version have some detrimental interactions with brewing. However, not being familiar with the mod I cannot say whether or not this is the case. If it were the case though, it would likely only affect some of the plants that you would normally brew with. Also the [kitchen status screen](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Status#Kitchen_Status_Screen) will have a list of plants that will show which are allowed for brewing. This does assume that a modicum of quality control went into building the mod. If it somehow removed the ability of barrels to hold alcohol that would not show up in the kitchen status screen.

Some other situations that can make plants temporarily unavailable are mentioned by Mark Ripley:

- When a plant is involved in any job, including hauling to a stockpile, it is unavailable until that job ends. This starts the moment the plant is decided upon as the plant to use in the job, often long before it is picked up.
- [Burrow](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Burrow) restrictions can make plants unavailable across burrow boundaries.

Comment: It would seem that I was indeed out of plants, and it was just a coincidence that I was no longer out after reconstructing the Still.

Comment: Ah, this happens. If you manage to keep track of the job cancel announcement it will usually tell you what's missing, but there are usually a lot of them.

Comment: You might also add the following: 1) your plants or plant stockpile is outside of a burrow and the Still is inside the burrow, or 2) the plant is currently being transporting or stored by a dwarf and thus not available for brewing.

Comment: My earlier comment about a plant currently being transported by a dwarf being not available for brewing also applies to any plant that a dwarf is >>planning<< to move. Once a dwarf has decided to grab a plant and transport it to an appropriate food pile but has not yet arrived where the plant is located, that plant becomes un-available for brewing until he drops it again.